# editing password; status 400

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Please, I need help ;
in my ios app, user can create an account by editing a password;
but when this happens  I am getting HTTP status 400
I am trying to post the data on the server which asks for JSON format
Here's what I am doing

```
    NSLog(@"user_id: %@", user_id);

    NSString *oldPassword = self.txt_mdpss.text ;

    NSString *txtmdpss = self.txt_nv_mdpss.text ;



strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://mysite/wp-json/api/v1/user/editpasswd?user_id=%@&old_passwd=%@&new_passwd=%@",user_id,oldPassword,txtmdpss];

   strUrl = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [manager GET:strUrl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {



        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];



        NSLog(@"REPOONSE EDITER MOT DE PASSE  = %@", responseObject );



        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {



            NSMutableArray *responseArray = responseObject;



        } else if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {



            NSDictionary *responseDict = responseObject;



            NSLog(@"-------------------> Response Editer Profile = %@",responseObject);



            //NSString *strIDUser = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[responseDict objectForKey:@"user_id"]];



            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];



            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"no" forKey:@"isConnectedFromFB_notHavePsswd"];
```

Comment: Status 400 means Bad request I think there wrong in your url or type of service POST not GET , please check that

Comment: That's a good way to leave passwords strewn throughout your server's log file.